# xcode 7.2 clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: xcode7.2

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

I am getting an error when archiving a binary.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

google analytics doesn't support bitcode so I ended up with disabling bitcode in settings to get rid of this error

Comment: It helped me. Thanks.

Comment: You literally saved a life. I was at the edge of 19th floor's roof wall.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is crashing.  Click on the error, it will take you to the full log; sometimes there is more info there.

If this is Swift then it was happening to me a lot when making mistakes with blocks (e.g. missing a return or returning the wrong type).  But it could be anything.  You have to figure out what is causing the crash.

Also, upgrade to Xcode 7.3; maybe it is fixed there.  You need to anyway if you're going to submit that app.

Comment: I realized that google analytics doesn't support bitcode and it gave this error

Comment: it's not possible to upload an app using xCode 7.2?