# Unity 3d IL2CPP not archiving

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I have a Unity 3d project and if I build it with Mono 2x Scripting backend and Universal Architecture, it works perfectly in Xcode; ie it builds, I can run on a device and Archive for submission to the App Store.

However this fails to upload to app store due to lack of 64 bit support.

I researched and found that you are supposed to change the Scripting backend to IL2CPP and made that change.

Now the project builds fine in Xcode and I can run it on a device, but when I come to Archive it, I get the following errors:

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried disabling BitCode [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36269845/3482632)

and I have tried changing Optimization to Faster.

I have checked and this issue is affecting others as well. I am using Xcode 7.2.1

Does anyone have any insight to this.

Comment: did you build a new xCode project or did you overwrite the Native, Data and Libraries folders in old xCode project?

Comment: What file was being compiled when the Segmentation fault occurred?  Does it work in Xcode 7.3?

Comment: @NikaKasradze I simply created a new build via Unity and replaced the existing Mono build. trojanfoe - I cant decipher the log. I cant get 7.3 to work !!

Comment: a lot of people are having the same issue it seams: [see this](https://www.google.ge/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xcode+Segmentation). most of them have some missing functions and stuff. so maybe updating Unity could help with this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, After some more digging, it seems that in my case it needed a two pronged attack.

Firstly, Unity build includes libiconv2.dylib in the project list and in the frameworks.

When I removed this from the project and the list of frameworks and then added libiconv.2.tda and cleaned the project, the first error went away.

I then changed Bitcode to NO and cleaned the project and this time it archived just fine.

I don't know if any of the other issues are connected, but that is how I fixed mine.

It appears to me to be a Unity Bug and should be raised with them as it is not accounting for the latest changes in XCode.